# Bug in adding configurable product to cart pop up

Tags: cart

When I select a product of specific color of  a configurable product and add it to cart, In cart pop up Two products are displayed one indicating the color and the other is simply the product name with image. I need to display exactly the selected color product in the cart pop up. Kindly someone help me to do this.

This is my code to display selected items in cart pop up:

```
<?php foreach($items as $_item): ?>
<?php $isVisibleProduct = $_item->getProduct()->isVisibleInSiteVisibility();?>
<?php $product = $_item->getProduct(); ?>
<?php echo "<ul> <li class='item'>"; ?>
<span class="cart-img"><a href="<?php echo $product->getProductUrl() ?>" title="<?php echo $this->stripTags($this->getImageLabel($_product, 'small_image'), null, true) ?>" class="product-image"><img src="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($product, 'small_image')->resize(50, 50); ?>" width="50" height="50" alt="<?php echo $this->stripTags($this->getImageLabel($product, 'small_image'), null, true) ?>" /></a></span>
<span class="cart-name"><?php echo $_item->getName();?></span>
<span class="cart-qty"><?php echo $_item->getQty();?></span>
<span class="cart-price"><?php echo $this->helper('checkout')->formatPrice($_item->getCalculationPrice()+$_item->getWeeeTaxAppliedAmount()+$_item->getWeeeTaxDisposition()); ?></span>
<?php $url=$this->getUrl('checkout/cart/delete',array('id'=>$_item->getId())); ?>
<span class="cart_item_delete" ><a href="<?php echo $url ?>" title="<?php echo $this->__('Remove This Item') ?>" onclick="return confirm('<?php echo $this->__('Are you sure you would like to remove this item from the shopping cart?') ?>');" class="btn-remove"><?php echo $this->__('Remove This Item') ?></a></span>  
<?php echo "</li></ul>" ?>  
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

What should be changed here to display the exactly the configurable product with selected color?

Comment: Might be this can help you
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28477149/get-configurable-options-in-minicart-magento

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
$quote = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote();
$cartItems = $quote->getAllVisibleItems();
foreach ($cartItems as $item) {

  $options = $item->getProduct()->getTypeInstance(true)->getOrderOptions($item->getProduct());
  //Do something

}
```

Comment: I tried your code. The Page is showing error.

Comment: I have updated my answer

Comment: should I wrap my code inside this for loop?

Comment: Yes, You can put your suitable code instead of `Do something`

Comment: Hey thank you thank you soo much. I got It. But as  In my screen shot above, Now am getting Product name displayed. I just wanted to display the product name with selected color. How to display that.

Comment: Check updated answer. Just print that `$options` variable

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/34347/discussion-between-rohit-kundale-and-ramya).

Comment: I changed `<span class="cart-name"><?php echo $_item->getName();?></span>` to `<span class="cart-name"><?php echo $options?></span>` But page disappeared

Comment: `$options` is an array. print it. you will get option as array

Comment: I am just a beginner in php. Can you please guide me regarding that. When I print that like `<span class="cart-name"><?php echo $options?></span>, The word 'Array' is displayed in place of the product name

Comment: echo '<pre>';
  print_r($options);
  Put this instead of `$options`. You will get `$options` array. then you can use this proper way using array keys

Comment: Printing That $option gives array code in cart pop up

Comment: can you please show me that array code. come in discussion chat